# How to allow comment author to reply to comments on his posts

Tags: 7, rules, comments

The answer to "[How to restrict node authors from commenting on their own nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191401/how-to-disallow-a-user-to-comment-on-their-own-nodes/191438#191438)" includes a rule that unpublishes comments made by an author on his own posts. The rule works and is reproduced below.

```
{ "rules_unpublish_selected_comments" : {
    "LABEL" : "Unpublish selected comments",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "comment" ],
    "ON" : { "comment_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "comment:node:author" ], "value" : [ "comment:author" ] } }
],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "comment:status" ], "value" : "0" } } ]
  }
}
```

To refine it further, how would you modify the rule so that the comment author could reply to comments made by others on his own post or node?

Comment: I would suggest you to rethink the approach of using that rule. Giving user an ability to post a comment, and seconds after make them realize that it will never be published - is just not a very good user experience.

Comment: Not sure I understand what your actual question is here. But could it be that your last word of your question should be "node", and not "comment"? Also, maybe you should add a sample scenario with a node , then author of the node, one or more users who post a comment, and then explain what exactly you'd want to allow or disallow...

Comment: When a user leaves a comment on a comment, there is a "reply" link under his comment. What I am trying to do is allow the author of the original comment to reply to that second comment.

Comment: @oksana-c : would that rule seem more acceptable to you by just adding another Rules Action to display a Drupal message to inform that user about the automatic unpublish (to teach them while they are not respecting the rules)?

Comment: But @oksana may be right. Maybe hiding the comment form from the comment author is a better approach. It's food for thought.

Comment: @PierreVriens - Thanks for pointing out the error. I'll make the correction.

Comment: Is there a comment depth value in the Rule's condition. If so with depth 1 you unpublish and with depth greater than 1 you don't

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - The approach comes across as inefficient and non-intuitive. Users are creatures of habit and they want to see the results of their actions. Can't really dig much deeper without knowing the use case. Most web users' habits are already established, the dominance of social media made it so. Mind as well give humans what they are used to.

Comment: @user14666 - take a look at [Comment Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_perm) module and permission that it provides out of the box. It is very easy to extend the functionality of it with custom permissions, as it is structured very nicely. Adding your own custom permissions logic like "Comment on own nodes of type" and "Reply on own nodes of type" might be just the right solution for your question. It'll also cover the use of AJAX comments it you ever decide to use it.

Comment: @oksana-c : I can understand your viewpoint. However, consider that approach as resolving an issue "*after the issue occurred*",  as an alternative for an approach that "*prevents it from happening*" (similar to pro-active versus re-active remedies for all sorts of problems). I'd leave it to a site owner to decide which approach fits best.